# multiple choice dropdown with option groups using symfony “entity”?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have the entity Property with manyToMany to Feature that is oneToMany of FeatureType. The multi-choice drop-down is being implemented in the Property create form.

```
PropertyRoomAdmin.php

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $property = $this->getProperty();
        $featuresChoices = $this->getRepository('TestBundle:Feature')->getChoicesWithCategoryGroup();

        $formMapper

            ->add('features', 'entity', array(
                'label' => '設備（こだわり条件？）',
                'class' => 'TestBundle:Feature',
                'choices' => $featuresChoices,
                'property' => 'name'
            ))

        ;
    }
```

FeatureRepository.php

```
public function getChoicesWithCategoryGroup()
    {
        $choices = array();

        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
        $qb->select('p, c');

        $qb->LeftJoin('p.featureCategory', 'c');
        $qb->orderBy('c.name', 'DESC')->addOrderBy('p.name', 'DESC');

        $products = $qb->getQuery()->execute();

        $choices = [];
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $choices[$product->getFeatureCategory()->getName()][] = $product;
        }

        return $choices;
    }
```

> **Neither the property "features" nor one of the methods "addFeatur()"/"removeFeatur()", "addFeature()"/"removeFeature()",
>   "setFeatures()", "features()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have
>   public access in class "TestBundle\Entity\PropertyRoom".**

I tried **'multiple' => true** code got error

```
 ->add('features', 'entity', array(
            'label' => '設備（こだわり条件？）',
            'class' => 'EstateBundle:Feature',
            'choices' => $featuresChoices,
            'property'  => 'name',
            'multiple'=> true,
            'required' => false
        ))
```

> ERROR - Failed to create object: EstateBundle\Entity\PropertyRoom 
>   Context: {"exception":"Object(Sonata\AdminBundle\Exception\ModelManagerException)","previous_exception_message":"An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO property_room_features (property_room_id, feature_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [168, 50]:\n\nSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '168-50' for key 'PRIMARY'"}

Comment: Does your entity have any of the functions stated in the error.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing a property entity to your form? The error seems to say you are attempting to set features on a propertyRoom

Answer (score 0):

Where you setup your options array:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
        $choices[$product->getFeatureCategory()->getName()][] = $product;
    }
```

Change it to something like this:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
        $choices[$product->getFeatureCategory()->getName()][$product->getName()] = $product->getId();
    }
```